# How to make async function work sequential when an object is updated inside it that is to be returned

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, promise, async-await

I am trying to update a map inside my async function so I want the map to be returned only when the loop has executed but the undefined value is returned first that breaks my code. How to defer this return statement?

```
async function getResourceDataMap(stationCode, event) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let sheetIndexMap = await readXlsxFile(file, { getSheets : true} );
    let resourceDataMap = {};

    /*
         Consider all the sheets
         */
      sheetIndexMap.map(async (sheet) => {
      let sheetName = sheet.name;

      if(isSheetNameValid(sheetName)) {
        console.log("Entered for sheetName::" + sheetName);
        let sheetRows = await readXlsxFile(file, { sheet: sheetName });
        if (sheetRows != null && sheetRows.length > 1) { // we need atleast two rows
            let headers = sheetRows[0];
            console.log("header obtained is:" +headers);

            if(isColumnNamesValid(sheetName, headers)) {
                let sheetMapList = getSheetMap(sheetRows);
                console.log("SheetMapList obtained is:" + sheetMapList);

                // STEP : Create a map of the various sheets (corresponding to each resource type)
                console.log("SheetName here is::::::::" +sheetName);
                resourceDataMap[sheetName] = {
                    headerRows: headers,
                    sheetMapList : sheetMapList
                };
                console.log("Resource data Map within :" + resourceDataMap["PRE_STAGING_AREA"]);
            }
        }
      }
    })
    console.log("Resource data Map HEREEEE :" + resourceDataMap["PRE_STAGING_AREA"]);
    return resourceDataMap;
```

}

resourceDataMap is being updated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `async` callback for `map` which it returns the array of promises. So store the promise array in a variable and then do Promise.all at the end.

**Like this**

```js
async function getResourceDataMap(stationCode, event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  let sheetIndexMap = await readXlsxFile(file, { getSheets: true });
  let resourceDataMap = {};

  const promiseArr = sheetIndexMap.map(async (sheet) => { //<---- store array of promises obtained by map in a variable
    let sheetName = sheet.name;

    if (isSheetNameValid(sheetName)) {
      console.log("Entered for sheetName::" + sheetName);
      let sheetRows = await readXlsxFile(file, { sheet: sheetName });
      if (sheetRows != null && sheetRows.length > 1) {
        // we need atleast two rows
        let headers = sheetRows[0];
        console.log("header obtained is:" + headers);

        if (isColumnNamesValid(sheetName, headers)) {
          let sheetMapList = getSheetMap(sheetRows);
          console.log("SheetMapList obtained is:" + sheetMapList);

          // STEP : Create a map of the various sheets (corresponding to each resource type)
          console.log("SheetName here is::::::::" + sheetName);
          resourceDataMap[sheetName] = {
            headerRows: headers,
            sheetMapList: sheetMapList,
          };
          console.log(
            "Resource data Map within :" + resourceDataMap["PRE_STAGING_AREA"]
          );
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return Promise.all(promiseArr).then(x => { //<----make sure to do return here
      console.log(
        "Resource data Map HEREEEE :" + resourceDataMap["PRE_STAGING_AREA"]
      );
      return resourceDataMap;
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi @gdh, my map values are also populating out of order. can you please suggest in this? like the headers and sheetMapList are exchanged for different keys.